# Different ways of using enumerate

Tags: python, enumerate

I know the basic way that `enumerate` works, but what difference does it make when you have two variables in the for loop? I used `count` and `i` in the examples below

This code:

```python
Letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for count, i in enumerate(Letters):
    print(count, i)
```

and this:

```python
Letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in enumerate(Letters):
    print(i)
```

Both give the same output, this:

```python
>>>
    0 'a'
    1 'b'
    2 'c'
```

Is writing code in the style of the first example beneficial in any circumstances? What is the difference?
If you know any other ways that could be useful, just let me know, I am trying to expand my knowledge within python

Comment: `Enumerate` always returns a tuple, you are just unpacking the tuple into 2 variables in your first example. In your second example if you just needed the letter you would have to put `i[1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example, `count` is set to the index, and `i` is set to the element.

In the second example, `i` is being set to the 2-element tuple (index, element).

The first example is equivalent to:

```
count, i = 0, 'a'
```

which is the same as:

```
count = 0
i = 'a'
```

And the second example is the same as:

```
i = (0, 'a')
```

Comment: In this case, the element would be `['a','b','c']` right?

Comment: The assignment is being done in a loop, which means that (in the second example) `i` is being set to `(0,'a')`, *then* to `(1,'b')`, *then* to `(2,'c')`. They don't exist at the same time.